# c# combine factors into one

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'll try to word this the best I can. I want to have multiple factors and make them equal one **reusable** factor. As an example I am doing a speech recognition project and I want sup to represent a list of words.

EX: (Don't even know if an if statement is right for the job.)

```
var lower = speech.ToLower();
{
  if (lower.Contains("hello") || lower.Contains("hi") || lower.Contains("hey"))                    
    {                        
      object == sup;                    
    }
}
```

This way sup now represents hello, hi, and hey, making things more simple. Once again, I don't even know if an if statement is right for the job or if having sup be an object is right for this type of scenario. I hope this makes sense and thank you!

Comment: If you use `if`, let me say my condolences in advance to whomever is working with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, create a Dictionary which holds a list of values from one side and the responses on the other side.

```
private IDictionary<List<String>, List<String>> _responses = new Dictionary<List<String>, List<String>>();

_responses.Add(
            new List<String> { "Hello there!", "Hey mate", "Hi!" }},
            new List<String> { "sup" );

_responses.Add(
            new List<String> { "Buddy", "Mate", "Hombre" }},
            new List<String> { "sup");
```

Now in order to retrieve something:

```
foreach(var keyword in _responses.Keys){
 if(keywords.Contains("sup"){
  return _responses[keyword];
 }
}
```

Searching for "sup" will return you a list of appropriate responses. I've used a `List<String>` for lookup values as well, just so you can link multiple keywords to the same search results.

if you're going to enter a string consisting of multiple values, just add an outer loop to it:

Entire rewrite:

This example assumes you have an input string. Your requirement is to check if this input string contains any of a group of words. Every group of words should be able to be referenced trough a single word.

```
void Main()
{
    var babel = new Babel("hi homies, this is for my mate out there.");
    if(babel.HasAnswer("sup") && babel.HasAnswer("friend")){
        Console.WriteLine ("It has both!");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine ("Boo Jeroen you suck");
    }
}

public class Babel {
    private IDictionary<List<String>, List<String>> _responses = new Dictionary<List<String>, List<String>>();
    private String query;

    public Babel(string query){
        this.query = query;
        _responses.Add(
                new List<String> { "sup" },
                new List<String> { "hello", "hey", "hi"});

        _responses.Add(
                new List<String> {"friend" },
                new List<String> { "buddy", "mate", "hombre" });
    }

    public bool HasAnswer(string input){

     foreach(var token in input.Split(' ')) {
      foreach(var keyword in _responses.Keys){
        if(keyword.Contains(token)){
         return ContainsAny(_responses[keyword]);
        }
      }
     } 
     return false;
    }

    private bool ContainsAny(List<String> toCompare){
        foreach(string item in toCompare){
            foreach(string token in query.Split(' ')){
                if(token == item) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;               
    }


}
```

Output:

> It has both!

Benefit of this approach: adding a new group of words is as easy as adding an entry to the dictionary. Very high extensibility! You can also let multiple values reference to the same list (if you'd like to create "howdie" which should reference the same values as "sup", you can just add it to the list and it's done).

Comment: If this is not what you're looking for (which would surprise me), let me know.

Comment: I'm understanding the dictionary; however, it's reusing the "sup" that represents all the words in the dictionary that I'm not grasping. I'm wanting to re use "sup" in an if statement later on. Lets say the word "friend" is in the same situation as "sup" as in it represents many other words through a dictionary. I want to use sup and friend in this manner: if(sup && friend) == true {Rest of Program}. I hope that makes sense. This really is helping a lot.

Comment: @Holden: I believe I misunderstood your question the first time. Check my edited answer, I believe it now does what you want.

Comment: Do I need to put the library in its own class or in the main body of the program?

Comment: Do you mean the dictionary? I would put it in a separate class, like you can see here (`Babel`).

Comment: Yes I did! Thank you. I'll see about building it that way. Another thing, Do I need to make sure I have {switch (speech)} In the dictionary class to identify the list of words as the speech coming in? Or will having "sup" being under a {switch (speech)}in the main body of the program be enough?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean. If it feels like that's a job meant for the class that holds the dictionary than you should do it there. Generally you want to keep your main class as minimal as possible.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and I think you just about answered my question. I'll put the speech switch in the dictionary class and experiment with it. I am not horribly saturated with c# so this has been a huge help and great learning experience. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multiple inputs to point to one output then a `Dictionary` looks like a good option.  Notice in the `constructor` I use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as the `IEqualityComparer<string>` which Gets a `StringComparer` object that performs a case-insensitive ordinal string comparison so you don't need to mess with `Sting.ToLower()` when using keys on the `Dictionary`.

```
Dictionary<string,string> simple = new Dictionary<string,string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    {"hello", "sup"},
    {"hi", "sup"},
    {"hey", "sup"}
}
```

To find the proper response you could loop over the `KeysCollection` as follows.  Since you're not passing a key into the dictionary I think you would need to use ToLower() here.

```
string response = string.Empty;
foreach (string s in simple.Keys)
{
    if (speech.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))
    {
        response = simple[s];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what Harrison said, but I would use TryGetValue as below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        interface Word
        {
            String GetResponse();
        }

        public class Sup : Word
        {
            public String GetResponse()
            {
                return "Hello back to you!";
            }
        }

        public class Lates : Word
        {
            public String GetResponse()
            {
                return "Sorry to see you go.";
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sup = new Sup();
            var lates = new Lates();
            var mapping = new Dictionary<String, Word>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            {
                {"hi", sup},
                {"hello", sup},
                {"hey", sup},
                {"bye", lates},
                {"later", lates},
                {"astalavista", lates},
            };

            Word word;
            if (mapping.TryGetValue("HELLO", out word))
                Console.WriteLine(word.GetResponse());

            if (mapping.TryGetValue("astalavista", out word))
                Console.WriteLine(word.GetResponse());

            if (mapping.TryGetValue("blaglarg", out word))
                Console.WriteLine(word.GetResponse());
        }
    }
}
```